Error with Docker configuration for PNPM mono repo
I'm docker beginner, try to make configuration for my fullstack API REST project, I have 2 apps in my PNPM workspace, a frontend and a backend, frontend is Angular, and backend is AdonisJS, I want to make Docker configuration for : Phpmyadmin, Mysql, Angular and Adonis, but i have this problem :
That's my project structutre :
APPS /

BACKEND

DOCKERFILE


FRONT END
docker-compose

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'ts-node' imported from /app/apps/backend/ace.js

This is my docker-compose :
version: '3.8'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    volumes:
      - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    networks:
      - default
    environment:
      # MySQL
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: database
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
  phpmyadmin:
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
    restart: always
    networks:
      - default
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: mysql
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    depends_on:
      - mysql
  adonisjs:
    build: ./apps/backend
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "3333:3333"
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    environment:
      - APP_KEY=xxxxx
      - DB_CONNECTION=mysql
      - DB_HOST=mysql
      - DB_PORT=3306
      - DB_USER=user
      - DB_PASSWORD=password
      - DB_DATABASE=database
networks:
  default:
    driver: bridge
volumes:
  mysql_data:


And this is my Dockerfile :
FROM node:20-slim AS base
ENV PNPM_HOME="/pnpm"
ENV PATH="$PNPM_HOME:$PATH"
RUN corepack enable

FROM base AS build
COPY . /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN --mount=type=cache,id=pnpm,target=/pnpm/store pnpm install

COPY wait-for-it.sh /usr/wait-for-it.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/wait-for-it.sh
RUN pnpm add ts-node -D
CMD /usr/wait-for-it.sh mysql:3306 -- pnpm dev:all

EXPOSE 3333

Thanks for helping : )

You shouldn't need to override the working_dir: or inject code via volumes: in normal use.  In your particular setup, your Dockerfile is building an image, but then you're using runtime configuration to inject a second copy of the application in a different directory, and trying to run that instead.  Does deleting those two Compose options help?
